# Is there an open 'project' file format alternative to Microsoft's *.mpp?

Tags: project-management

There's the open document format (ODF) for word processors, but is there an open standardised format for project files? I'm currently using [Gnome Planner](http://live.gnome.org/Planner) which I downloaded from the Software Centre, but my course teaches us to use [OpenProj](http://openproj.org/), which I don't really like since it's pretty sluggish on my computer. I'm attempting to import the `*.planner` file from Planner into OpenProj, but it's not working. Planner exports to three different file format: `*.planner`, `*.mrproject` and *`.html` and none of them can be imported to OpenProj, whose default filetype is `*.pod` and can also export to `*.xml` and *`.pdf`. This all seems a bit messy to me.

Answer (score 0):

A visit to http://www.osalt.com yielded a link to [GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/). Among the features listed on their website is the ability to "import projects from and export them to Microsoft Project formats [and] export to spreadsheets with CSV."

I have no experience with this type of software but osalt.com would always be my first stop for a question like this.

Comment: I guess this doesn't answer the file format question very precisely, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/

> OpenProj is an open-source desktop project management application similar to Microsoft Project. OpenProj has a familiar user interface and even opens existing MS Project files. OpenProj is interoperable with Project, Gantt Charts and PERT charts.

[image]

Comment: openproj is dead. ProjectLibre is an actively maintained fork: http://www.projectlibre.org/ - it is able to open .planner files.

Answer (score 0):

[ProjectLibre](http://www.projectlibre.org/) is an actively maintained fork of openproj that is able to open .planner files.